# How can I get around the ModuleNotFoundError when importing from bs4?

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to build a program to extract text from html for translation purposes. I installed python and bs4 in the command prompt and copied some code from another person that should do what I want. Each time I run it inside PyCharm, I get an error. I'm not sure how to proceed with this problem.

Edit: I figured out what was going on. I added import bs4 to my python file

from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import bs4

After this, windows asked me if I wanted to install bs4 (never had this happen before). I installed it that way.

I then added bs4 to the soup variable
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

Ran the script and it's doing exactly what I want it to.

```py
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_playing_cards"

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print(text)
```

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#
Have you installed it with pip?

Comment: Yes, I installed it with pip.

Comment: Did you make sure that the python which you installed pip packages and the one that you use to run your script are the same? Interpreter in Pycharm should be the same as the one that you use to install bs4

Comment: I only have python 3. Do file locations affect anything?